# How can I parse this response in a model class

Tags: arrays, json, api, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm trying to parse a json response in model class.
This is the response.
I'm not able to parse it properlly.

```
[
    {
        "ranges": [
            {
                "lat": 21.8969425959248,
                "lng": 87.12079044431448
            },
            {
                "lat": 21.896755942991668,
                "lng": 87.12070394307375
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ranges": [
            {
                "lat": 21.897269860144323,
                "lng": 87.12018627673388
            },
            {
                "lat": 21.897339854770518,
                "lng": 87.12001327425241
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried adding the response to this models

```
data class RangesModel(
    @SerializedName("ranges" ) var ranges : ArrayList<Ranges> = arrayListOf()
)
```

```
data class Ranges(
    @SerializedName("lat" ) var lat : Double? = null,
    @SerializedName("lng" ) var lng : Double? = null
)
```

But was not able to parse it properlly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's failing for you is that your JSON actually has the format of `List<RangesModel>` as it starts and ends with the [] braces. So it's not an object but a list of objects.

If you use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` you could deserialize them into such simplified model (note that values aren't nullable anymore so both lat and lng are required)

```
data class Ranges(
    @JsonProperty("ranges")
    val ranges: List<Range>
)
data class Range(
    val lat: Double,
    val lng: Double
)
```

using following code

```
val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
val deserialized = objectMapper.readerForArrayOf(Ranges::class.java)
    .readValue<Array<Ranges>>(json)
```

Also, note that creating `objectMapper` is an expensive operation so you don't want to do it for each deserialization

Comment: I did add same code but got error.

Cannot construct instance of `com.ctech.models.Range` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
        at [Source: (String)"[{"ranges":[{"lat":21.8962821545322,"lng":87.11984865367413},{"lat":21.896333795373117,"lng":87.11963843554258},{"lat":21.89644018789003,"lng":87.11"[truncated 2192 chars]; line: 1, column: 14] (through reference chain: java.lang.Object[][0]->com.ctech.models.Ranges["ranges"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])

Comment: val jsonString = response.body()!!.string()

val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
val deserialized = objectMapper.readerForArrayOf(Ranges::class.java).readValue<List<Ranges>>(jsonString)

This is the code I added.

Comment: Please try to add @JsonProperty for lat and lng fields like that

data class Range(
   @JsonProperty("lat")
    val lat: Double,
    @JsonProperty("lng")
    val lng: Double
)

Comment: Showing this now
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ctech.models.Ranges[] cannot be cast to java.util.List

data class Range(
    @JsonProperty("lat") val lat: Double,
    @JsonProperty("lng") val lng: Double
)

Comment: That's strange, I tested my answer before posting but now it's also failing with the same error :) As the error says, it can't convert Array to List, changing it to eadValue<Array<Ranges>>(json) helps. I will also update the answer

Comment: Everything is nullable in JSON, therefore everything must be nullable in models. Otherwise you risk the parser making up values like `0.0` without you even realizing something went wrong.

Comment: If you have nullable fields in the model that should be required you risk to deserialize bad data and try to process it. Having not nullable fields in the model guarantees to fail fast in case of the bad data, it will not be parsed into 0.0 

Comment: @fedden That depends on parser. Most parsers make up missing values, hence 0.0. That's the exact opposite of failing fast.

Comment: I agree it depends on the parser, but in case Jackson that is probably most popular library for (de)serialization for java and also is used in my answer it will fail if there are missing  fields 

Answer (score -1):

How about using ObjectMapper?
You can read more here: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial

In your case You would probably need to use something like:

```
Ranges ranges = objectMapper.readValue(json, Ranges.class);
```